# format decimal values in grid

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to achieve custom formatting for few retrieved fields which are decimal in DB. I have data like `1122.454540000` in my price field. I want to show that in a grid after custom formating. I want to show four digits after decimal point if least one of first four fields after decimal isn't zero. If i have field like `1122.000100` i want to show that as `1122.0001` but i have values like `9876.000000` then i want to show only 9876 without any decimal points. Currently everything is working fine with

```
string.Format("{0:F4}", Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Price")))
```

But i am having one issue for a specific case. When i get values like `1122.4000` or `1122.5400`, that is only showing `1122.4` and `1122.54` instead of showing all four digits regardless of if last trailing digits are zeros. Any idea if i am approaching this in right direction?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: What about 42.0000001 ? Do you want 42 or 42.0000 ?

Answer (score 1):

### If you want 42.0000001 to be formated 42

The solution below can be modified to do it.
But basically, you just want to remove `.00..` from your string.

You can do it by using RegEx:

```
public string Format(string format, double value)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"^(?<IntPart>.*)([.,]0*)$");
    var s = String.Format("{0:F4}", value);
    var match = regex.Match(s);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        return match.Groups["IntPart"].Value;
    }
    return s;
}

Console.WriteLine(Format("{0:F4}", 1.35687));    // 1.3569
Console.WriteLine(Format("{0:F4}", 1.35));       // 1.3500
Console.WriteLine(Format("{0:F4}", 1));          // 1
Console.WriteLine(Format("{0:F4}", 42.000001));  // 42
```

### If you want 42.0000001 to be formated 42.0000.

You need to test for the decimal part of the value (to be exactly 0).

The only way I see to perform it *nicely* is to use a [ICustomFormatter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.icustomformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I will *create* the **F_XX** format, which is **F0** or **FXX** depending on whether the variable is an integer or not. (In your case **F_4** will be **F0** or **F4**).

Here a first attempt, :

```
public class MyCustomFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    // Match "F_XX" where XX are digits.
    private readonly Regex _regex = new Regex("F_(?<DigitCount>\\d+)");

    // IFormatProvider.GetFormat implementation.
    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        // Determine whether custom formatting object is requested.
        if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
            return this;
        else
            return null;
    }

    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        var shouldUseF0 = false;

        var match = _regex.Match(format);

        // Detect F_XX format.
        if (match.Success)
        {
            // Manage float.
            if (arg is float)
            {
                if (((float) arg)%1 == 0)
                {
                    shouldUseF0 = true;
                }
            }

            // Manage double.
            if (arg is double)
            {
                if (((double) arg)%1 == 0)
                {
                    shouldUseF0 = true;
                }
            }

            // TODO: Manage int, long...

            if (shouldUseF0)
            {
                format = "F0";
            }
            else
            {
                // Build the FXX format.
                format = "F" + match.Groups["DigitCount"].Value;
            }
        }

        if (arg is IFormattable) return ((IFormattable)arg).ToString(format, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        if (arg != null) return arg.ToString();
        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Here the result:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(cf, "{0:F_4}", 1.35678));  // 1.3568
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(cf, "{0:F_4}", 1.35));     // 1.3500
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(cf, "{0:F_4}", 1.00));     // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string.Format("{0:#.0000}", Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Price")))
```

`#` stands for any digits, `0` stands for `0` if there is no digit, or digit itself.
[More on MSDN about the Custom Numeric formatting in .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).
Unfortunately, **this approach woudn't work** if you want to hide zeroes for the integer numbers.

[Great article mentioned in other answer](http://www.daveoncsharp.com/2009/09/formatting-decimals-in-csharp/)

> **Setting a Fixed Amount of Decimal Places**
>   This is similar to the above example but instead of hashes (‘#’) in our format string we are
>   going to use zeroes (‘0’) as shown below:
>
> ```
> string.Format("{0:0.00}", 256.583); // "256.58"
> string.Format("{0:0.00}", 256.586); // "256.59"
> string.Format("{0:0.00}", 256.58);  // "256.58"
> string.Format("{0:0.00}", 256.5);   // "256.50"
> string.Format("{0:0.00}", 256.0);   // "256.00" - No luck here
> ```

**Update**:
As I said, this won't work for not showing the leading zeroes if number has no numbers in fractional part, so you can check with [`Math.Truncate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d101hyf.aspx) method before formatting:

```
var decimalValue = Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Price"));
string.Format((decimalValue - Math.Truncate(decimalValue)) < 0.0001 ? "{0:#.####}" : {0:#.0000}", decimalValue)
```

But this will provide a very huge overhead for your program.

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple as

```
  Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Price")), 4).ToString("N4")
```

> Console sample

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(1122.454540000, 4).ToString("N4"));  // output 1122.4545
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(1122.000100, 4).ToString("N4")); // output 1122.0001
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(9876.000000, 4).ToString("N4"));// output 9876.0000
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(1122.4000, 4).ToString("N4"));// output 1122.4000
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(1122.5400, 4).ToString("N4"));// output 1122.5400
            Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Comment: Is your answer for actual issue? according to question last two should be 1122.4000 and 1122.5400!

Comment: Your output for `1122.4` is `1122.4` instead of `1122.4000`, this is not what is asked.

Comment: Sorry I understand wrong..  Edited Answer  @yogi970 and @o

Comment: Your output for `9876.0` is `9876.0000` instead of `9876`, this is not what is asked. Also, you did not need `Math.Round` is you use standard format (N4,...).

Comment: Well thanks for reply but i don't want to round my data. I just want to show decimal part if any of first four digits aren't zero. My desired output for 1122.1 is 1122.1000 and for 1122.000 as 1122 only.

Answer (score 0):

#### If some workaround is possible then,try this

```
   double price= 12.00300;
   string op = null;
   price= Double.Parse(string.Format("{0:0.0000}", value));
   if ((price % 1) != 0)
     op =   string.Format("{0:#.0000}", price);
   else
     op =  string.Format("{0}", price);
```

> You can use it like utility function or you can change according to your requirement.

1. For 12.000000      =>  12
2. For 12.001000      =>  12.0010
3. For 12.333333      =>  12.3333

Comment: It will format `42.0000001` to `42.0000`. OP need `42`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the decimal is whole number and then use the appropriate format. An implementation with extension method:

```
 public static class DecimalExtension
  {
    public static string MyFormat(this decimal value)
    {
       decimal rounded = Math.Round(value, 4);
       if ((rounded % 1) == 0)
       {
         return rounded.ToString("0:0");
       }

        return rounded.ToString("0:0.0000");

      }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to check this out:
http://www.daveoncsharp.com/2009/09/formatting-decimals-in-csharp/

specifically:

```
string.Format("{0:0.00}", 256.0);   // "256.00"
```

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: Sorry, I realized it's probably too broad... added specific answer.